# Regex, select the number after a particular string

Tags: regex, hive

I have the below string:

```
rollover#7500,another1#3000,another2#4000, another1#7000
```

I need to extract the number that comes directly after rollover#

So far, I have this, but it's matching rollover#7500

```
(?:rollover#[0-9]*)
```

I'm not sure how to extract only the numbers?

I will be running this in a Hive query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
regexp_extract(your_col,'rollover#([0-9]+)', 1)
```

The `rollover#([0-9]+)` pattern [will find](https://regex101.com/r/PzRhpZ/1) `rollover#` and then will capture 1 or more digits into Group 1, the third `1` argument will make `regexp_extract` return just the Group 1 value.